# Proxies with NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm using `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` to make a connection to a server for my OS X app.

Now I would like to implement a specific proxy server connection but I cannot find something about it in the docs.

I want the web view to go straight through a proxy I define, not change the machine/device proxy settings.

Has anyone tried this or know how to handle proxies from within Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. I discovered that **ASIHTTPRequest** has the thing i need:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://minip.no"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setProxyHost:[chosenprox objectForKey:@"host"]];
[request setProxyPort:[[chosenprox objectForKey:@"port"] intValue]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
if ([request error]) {
    [mainFrame loadHTMLString:[[request error] localizedDescription] baseURL:nil];
} else if ([request responseString]) {
    [mainFrame loadHTMLString:[request responseString] baseURL:nil];
}
```

And it has other nice uses as well.